# Sim7600 TLS data buffer size?

Tags: iot, lte, simcom, sim800

I use sim7600 module's TLS layer to connect the Azure IoT hub. I have problem with tls buffer size, which is 2kb(as datasheet says). It acts unexpectedly when i try to receive message more than 2kb in size. When i send a message size 2.5kb from the Azure iot hub, sometimes i get the whole data and sometime i receive just 2kb and another portion of data is lost. As i observed another portion of data comes when automatic "peer socket close" command comes, or when another message is send from the Azure.

I am confusing what to do to get more than 2kb data in size over TLS.

Comment: Does anyone knows what is the problem?